# Installation of wxWidgets

Tags: linux, gui, raspbian, gtk

I'm currently trying to install 3.0.4 version of wxWidgets on a Raspbian Jessie. wxWidgets was successfully installed. However, when I try to run an application, the following relocation runtime error occurs.

```
relocation error: symbol_ZNK8wxWindow7IsShownEv, version WXU_3.0 not
defined in file libwx_gtk2u_core-3.0.so.0 with link time reference
```

Is anything need to be updated in LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable or should the wx_gtk2u_core-3.0 library be re-installed?

PS: The following commands were run to install wxWidgets

```
configure --with-gtk
make -j4
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```